# Set field to getdate() automatically without trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, default-constraint

I have a table t with a datetime field dbupddate. That field should reflect the last time the record was inserted/updated.

I have already made a default constraint to set it to getdate(), but that doesn't prevent a user to insert a non-default value.

I also do not have the authority to create a trigger or modify an existing one.

Is there a way to enforce the correct value of getdate() to be inserted/updated?

**From the comments, I deduce the short answer is no, and I received many useful suggestions. Thank you all.**

Comment: Sounds like a user issue; either they shouldn't be able to `INSERT` directly into the database (so need to use an SP, for example) or when they do they should be ensuring that use the `DEFAULT` value.

Comment: You should be using stored procedures from the front end. Then you would be able to handle this the way you need to. As already stated end users should not be directly inserting data.

Comment: You can't control the update (or insert) of that column in the manner you need without a trigger. Encapsulate the operation in a SP and force the users to insert or update data through it and only it.

Comment: short answer - no, impossible to do in a reliable manner. And default constraints, generally speaking, serve no purpose in an update.

Comment: I *suppose*, for the `INSERT` you could set up Column Level Permission and not allow the user(s) to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the value of your column; of course that won't cause the value of said column to change when they perform an `UPDATE`.

Comment: If you don't have the authority to create triggers on an existing table, you may still be allowed to create them on a new view created for this purpose (you can use some jiggery-pokery with default schemes and synonyms to ensure that when the user asks for the table, they actually get your view, and deny them permission on the base table) . Personally I would strongly prefer a stored procedure in this case, but an updatable view is still an option if your ability to change clients is limited.